# jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics does not work with com.intershop.gradle.jaxb 6.0.0

Tags: gradle, jaxb, jaxb2-basics

I tried to use new version of com.intershop.gradle.jaxb:6.0.0 with gradle:8.1.1 to generate java classes from wsdl. But I need jaxb2-basics extension to use '-XtoString' parameter. When I add

```
jaxbext 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1'
```

to my dependencies section and try to generate even without '-XtoString' parameter I have got an error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jaxbJavaGenCsClientWs'.
> xjc failed

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jaxbJavaGenCsClientWs'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
```

This is full configuration of my gradle project. I use java17.

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id 'com.intershop.gradle.jaxb' version '6.0.0'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${project.buildDir}/generated-java/csClientWs"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    testV = '4.7.472.60'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-jxc:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0'

    jaxbext 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    jaxbext 'net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons:jaxb-fluent-api:2.1.8'
    jaxbext 'com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin:jaxb-xew-plugin:2.1'

    //jaxbext 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1'

    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-ant:1.11.1'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:1.1.0'
}

jaxb {
    javaGen {
        csClientWs {
            strictValidation = false
            extension = true
            packageName = 'org.excample.csclient.ws'
            header = true
            schema = file("${projectDir}/src/main/wsdl/test_${testV}.wsdl")
            binding = file("${projectDir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xjb")
            args = ['-wsdl', '-Xxew', '-Xfluent-api']
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when I uncomment all section below jaxbext 'com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin:jaxb-xew-plugin:2.1' jaxb2-basics will work properly and when I will add '-XtoString' to args section it generate properly java Classes. When this section is commented (like in my example) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try these dependencies instead of the `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons` artifacts:

```
implementation 'org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-basicjaxb-ant:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.patrodyne.jvnet:hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin:2.1.0'
```

> Version 2.1.0 of the [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) project is a significant release, its source/target (release) compatibility is at Java 11, up from Java 8. And, JDK 17 is used for the build. JAXB dependencies are at version 4.x.

See also [BasicJAXB V2 namespace changes](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#version-200).

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer of the *HiSrc* forks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) to help get the latest version of the `org.jvnet.jaxb` artifacts, according the targeted JDK and JAXB API (v4 is a good one).

We also added in latest version the backport of the `jaxb-fluent-api`

So it would lead to the following configuration

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-jxc:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0'

    jaxbext 'com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin:jaxb-xew-plugin:2.1'
    jaxbext 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.0'

    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-ant:4.0.0'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-runtime:4.0.0'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.0'
    //implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugin-annotate:4.0.0'
}

jaxb {
    javaGen {
        csClientWs {
            strictValidation = false
            extension = true
            packageName = 'org.excample.csclient.ws'
            header = true
            schema = file("${projectDir}/src/main/wsdl/test_${testV}.wsdl")
            binding = file("${projectDir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xjb")
            args = ['-wsdl', '-Xxew', '-Xfluent-api', '-XtoString']
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the good args you want (added `-XtoString`) and uncomment the implementation section if needed.

I also found it strange you added the jaxb-api "2.4.0" as jaxbext, been removed in configuration above.